Unable to create project using flutter get cli and also installing get cli
I already install and create a project before, but today when i try to create a project with this command get create project:project_name its no longer working with this error: The term 'get' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
i try to install again the cli
cmd command:flutter pub global activate get_cli
Error:
Building package executables... (27.3s) Failed to build get_cli:get: AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/get_cli-1.8.4/lib/common/utils/pubspec/pubspec_lock.dart:4:8: Error: Error when reading 'AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/yaml-3.1.2/lib/yaml.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.
I try to deactived
cmd command: flutter pub global deactivate get_cli
Output:No active package get_cli.
